# Performace API issue

Tags: javascript, api, performance, browser, timestamp

I was following the example from the [MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark)on performance.mark() method which according to docs

> creates a timestamp in the browser's performance entry buffer with the given name.

Here is the example code again:

```
performance.mark("squirrel");
performance.mark("squirrel");
performance.mark("monkey");
performance.mark("monkey");
performance.mark("dog");
performance.mark("dog");

// return entries of specific type
let allEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("mark");
console.log(allEntries.length); // 6

// return entries that match the given name
const monkeyEntries = performance.getEntriesByName("monkey");
console.log(monkeyEntries.length); // 2

// clear all marks
performance.clearMarks();

// My code
console.log(allEntries); // 6 ???
console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("mark").length); // 0
console.log(performance.getEntriesByName("dog").length); // 0
console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("mark")); // []
```

Does anyone have an idea why the "allEntries" variable still has the array data after I clear all the marks with `performance.clearMarks()` method? Because in theory it supposed to look like an empty array which you can see in the last code line.

Comment: For the same reason that `let a = [1]; let b = a; a = [];` doesn't result in `b` being an empty array. If you did the call to `getEntriesByType` again, *that* would give you an empty array, but it doesn't reach out and empty the array you already have. Nothing in the description of the method suggests it returns a live view on the underlying data (like `getElementsByTagName` and such do). While it doesn't say so explicitly, not saying it's live suggests it's static (a snapshot), like the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Looking at the spec [here](https://w3c.github.io/performance-timeline/#dom-performance-getentriesbytype) which leads us [here](https://w3c.github.io/performance-timeline/#dfn-filter-buffer-map-by-name-and-type), it's clear it's a snapshot.

Comment: Thank u for responding, seems very simple all of a sudden. My thought process was when I'm clearing all the marks with clearMarks() method, the same would be applicable to 'allEntries' variable also.